# How can I use variables in pandoc to selectively render text to PDF?

Tags: conditional-statements, markdown, pandoc

I would like to write an exercise sheet using markdown and pandoc. The source of the exercise sheet contains the questions and the correct answers to the questions. I then want to render 2 different PDF documents, one with only the questions and another one including the answers as well.

I tried using a variable defined in the metadata section and then enclose the solutions in a block using that variable. But it didn't work. The text was always rendered.

I defined the variable `show-solution: false` in the metadata section and then created a block in the text like this:

```
## Task 1

A difficult problem

{{#if show-solution}}

And it's solution

{{/if}}
```

I also tried setting the value of the variable from the command line

```
pandoc my_document.md -o my_document.pdf --from markdown -V show-solution=false
```

It didn't work either.
I am using pandoc version 3.1.1

How can this be done? Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure that the solution to this is a pandoc filter. So I am creating another question about pandoc filters. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could mark your solutions with a [custom style](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles), use a metadata field (e.g. "hide_solutions") and use a filter like the following:

**tasks.md**:

```markdown
## Task 1

A difficult problem

::: {custom-style="Solution"}
And it's solution
:::
```

**tasks_filter.py**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from panflute import *
from panflute.utils import debug
from collections import OrderedDict

import pprint


def action(elem: Element, doc: Doc):
    if doc.hide_solutions:
        if hasattr(elem, 'attributes'):
            if 'custom-style' in elem.attributes:
                if elem.attributes['custom-style'] == "Solution":
                    return []


def prepare(doc: Doc):
    doc.hide_solutions = doc.get_metadata("hide_solutions", False)


def finalize(doc: Doc):
    del doc.hide_solutions


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_filters(
        [action],
        prepare=prepare,
        finalize=finalize
    )
```

The following will hide the solutions:

```bash
$ pandoc \
    -i tasks.md \
    -f markdown \
    -t markdown \
    --filter tasks_filter.py \
    --metadata=hide_solutions:true
```

And produce an output like:

```
## Task 1

A difficult problem
```

Use `--metadata=hide_solutions:false` to show the solutions

```
## Task 1

A difficult problem

::: {custom-style="Solution"}
And it's solution
:::
```

Note that in the above example `pandoc` outputs in markdown format to the stdout. This might be convenient for test purposes. Use `pandoc -i tasks.md -f markdown -t pdf -o tasks.pdf --filter tasks_filter.py --metadata=hide_solutions:false` to output a pdf.